# Counting points in polygon for subset of points layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, expression, point-in-polygon, count

I have a points layer with a column that separates the points into different types (e.g. *'high'*, *'medium'*, and *'low'*).

I need to count the number of points within polygons, for each of the different types.

At the moment, I'm doing it by creating a separate points layer for each of the types and then running the points within the polygon tool for each of them.
I was just wondering if there's a tool that lets you run points within polygon but with conditions so that I could run it for those points where the type is *'high'* etc?

Answer (score 2):

SQL is the answer!

You can achieve this using the DB Manager of QGIS.

You choose Database / Database Manager / Database Manager then Virtual Layers / QGIS Layers you can then try queries like the following:

```sql
SELECT count(*), pt_type
FROM pt_layer, poly_layer
WHERE st_intersects(pt.geometry, poly.geometry)
GROUP BY by pt_type
```

***pt_layer** being your point layer and **poly_layer** being your polygon layer...*

You can then load the result in the layer manager.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... Your instructions were great, but I'm getting an error message, and I'm not that familiar wtih SQL so can't figure it out... I've replaced pt_type, pt_layer and poly_layer with the names from my layers but it's telling me that 'pt.obj' isn't a layer. Do I also need to replace that with something? Or define what that is? I've tried replacing 'pt' with the name of my point layer but that didn't work. Thanks

Comment: sorry ... my mistake ... it was _"geometry"_ instead of _"obj"_ ...

Comment: That moves it past the first error, but I get a different error that I don't understand - pasted it at the end. "CombinedData" is a csv file I've uploaded to use as a layer. I've tried saving it as a shape file but that doesn't seem to make a difference. Does it need to be a layer in the main database for me to run the query or can it be held locally? Thanks.         Error message is: Query execution error on DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "CombinedData"; CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "CombinedData" USING QgsVLayer(CombinedData20190531140455318);: 1 - near "Order": syntax error

Comment: What role play the CombinedData table ? How is it connected to your first question ?

Comment: Sorry, didn't explain that properly. The CombinedData table is my points...  I used your code and amended as follows:    `code` SELECT count(*), Type from CombinedData, MSOAs
where st_intersects(CombinedData.geometry, MSOAs.geometry)
group by Type `code`

Comment: I don't see the problem ... maybe a problem with the naming of the tables ...  ? can u try to simplify the names (and maybe use only lowercase) ?

Comment: Did u solve it ... ?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this by using expressions - the function `overlay_within` is [available since QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/de/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core) (for older versions see the [refFunctions plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/)). You can achieve it in one step, however for clarity I explain it in two steps. If you want to do it in one step, simply replace `"polygon_id"` in the expression of step 2 with the whole expression from step 1.

Select the layer with your points and use the field calculator:

1. Create a new field `"polygon_id"` that contains the id (or any other unique value) for the polygon the points lays within. Replace `'polygon'` with the name of your polygon layer:

`array_first (overlay_within ( 'polygon', $id ) )`

2. Now count the number of features, grouped by the combination of your types (here: fieldname is `"value"`, change this accordingly) and the field `"polygon_id"` (the one from above):

`count ( $id, group_by:= "value" ||  "polygon_id" )`

You get the number of features for each type and each polygon separately.

*Screenshot with random points, see example highlighted with red rectangle: polygon 4 (see column `polygon_id`) contains 6 features/points (column `sum`) with the type/value 2 (column `value`)*
[image]

Comment: Where are we supposed to enter this line of code `count ( $id, group_by:= "value" ||  "polygon_id" )`? If I just run it in the field calculator, then it adds a number to each row in the layer table, but what we want is to have the summary for each "value".

Comment: As you can see in my screenshot, I indeed introduced the expression in the field calculator to create the field `sum`, so indeed I get repeating numbers for each feature with the same characteristics (same `value` and inside the same polygon). Depending on what kind of output you want, you could create an array or a key-value map to get kind of a list with unique values.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Yes I figured it out, was enough for me since I had a limited number of values, but I could imagine that it could get more problematic if I had had a high number of values.

Answer (score 1):

When I looked into this, I was surprised to see that there was no single tool that accomplished this task.  However, using 3.18, this can be solved with two tools:

Assume that the point layer has a field "type", as described in the original post.  Additionally, assume that the polygon layer has a field named "poly_code", where each polygon has a unique value (for example A, B, C...).

Use the **Intersection** tool, where the *Input Layer* = your point layer and the *Overlay layer* = your polygon layer.

The resulting output will be a new point layer containing the two input fields, "type" and "poly_code".  In other words, each point now contains the attributes from the matching polygons they fall within.

The final task is to count the number of points, by "type", within each polygon.  This is accomplished using the **Processing Toolbox > Statistics by Categories** tool, where the *Input Vector Layer* = the output point layer from the **Intersection** tool, and within the *Field(s) with Categories* option, both "type" and "poly_code" are checked on.

Voila!  The output table now contains a count for each "type" by "poly_code" combination.