# Count subset of points in polygons

Tags: qgis-3, sql, spatial-query, subset, feature-count

Being an SQL-noob, I found a working solution to generate a virtual layer with counts of points in the polygons of another layer, inspired by this 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/54680

```
SELECT polygons.fid,polygons.geometry, count(points.geometry) AS counts
FROM polygons
LEFT JOIN points
ON st_contains(polygons.geometry,points.geometry )
GROUP BY polygons.fid;
```

This returns a new polygon layer with the fid and the count of points.

But the end result I would like to achieve is, to only count a subset of points, represented by

```
points.controlled IS NULL
```

I can't find out where and how to inject this criteria into the query. All trial-and-error only led to the latter.

There is already a similar question, but the answer misses the subset part completely
[Counting points in a polygon for a subset of my points layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/324471)

Comment: nope, this gives just a count of 0. I would like to subset/filter/whatever the points layer to those points which are not NULL in the points.controlled column before being counted within the polygons. SQL-logic is so unlogical to me :(

Comment: @Cyril oh sorry, YES, it worked. The problem here was, that I queried an already joined layer, and there was a problem with he field names. Please post your answer and I will acknowledge it.

Comment: never mind, you answered correctly, Heikki was faster to post this as an answer. Thanx for your time and input!

Comment: Sorry @Cyril didn't see the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the filter in the join condition:

```
SELECT polygons.fid,polygons.geometry, count(points.geometry) AS counts
FROM polygons
LEFT JOIN points
ON st_contains(polygons.geometry,points.geometry) and points.controlled IS NULL
GROUP BY polygons.fid;
```